# Effective Way to Deal With TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a problem with table layout. My table consist of 24 row and 8 column. In tablet , it looks nice and fit. But in phone ,it looks very bad.

Is there a way to deal with Table Layout to looks it nice in the phone? Using any library or any suggestion?

Updated:

In Nexus 7 tablet. The interface is ok.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxFfs.png)

In Nexus 5x. This is the bad. The value will only shown half only.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niv9E.png)

The code is very long. NOTED: This is not my code. I am just getting a job for android dev and need to improve their code. I will shown only 1 row and 1 column only.

```
 <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabla_cuerpo1b"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tbrl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"

                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mainLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                        android:text="TPS"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/statView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                        android:text="RPM"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                         />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/speedL"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="\n"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ld1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:text="10%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ld2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:text="20%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ld3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:text="30%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ld4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:text="40%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ld5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:text="50%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ld6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:text="60%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ld7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:text="70%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ld8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:text="80%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            </TableRow>
```

Comment: Add your code for table layout

Comment: Also add some screenshots of the phone and tablets so we can understand what do you mean by "looks very bad"

Comment: @Muhammad Zawawi : Depends on your definition of NICE.. Put out some code samples and screen shots with your expectations. Then only SO can help you

Comment: I just update and forgive me this is my first time using stackoverflow and also my bad english. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I already figure out the best solution for now. The solution is to use SCROLLVIEW in order to use in 5 inch screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this 
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear). This is the full documentation of android. read carefully on `Weight` and `WeightSum`. `Weight` makes the layout more responsive and uses the same amount of space on the screen.

for e.g.

**NOTE** this is a `LinearLayout` example

if I want to add two `LinearLayout` Like this:

[image]

here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_circle"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I dont get it. This is about tablelayout. Not about linear layout.

Comment: I update the answer. Read on `weight` and `weightSum`

Comment: Don't forget to up vote and if it answer your question, mark this as a answer

Comment: thanks for reminding @VivekMishra. I'll take a note of it. still new here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @MikeGorospe much better now. Keep helping!!

Comment: I think this answer become more irrelevant. Mike I understand about linear layout all things. This is about table layout as you noticed it.

Comment: @MuhammadZawawi ok mate. but I think the solution is weight

Comment: nevermind Mike. I already try with the weight solution but  it is not. The only way to solve this is to design back all the things and making sure it realy fit 5 inch screen. Might be to reduce row and column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Constraint Layout** inside scroll view it will help you simplify the layout hierarchy and increase the performance significantly.